# Google Drive API - File have childrens or not

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-drive-realtime-api

I get files from google drive, like that. The result of **Folders**. ok,

I have **List result**, so I want to find if result(i) have **children** with application/vnd.google-apps.folder mime type or not.

in the other words,  method which checks: if current  folder  contains  children folder returns true. owherwise returns false;

I use it in google App engine.

how can I do that?

```
public   void getAllFiles(String id, Drive service) throws IOException{

        String query="'"+id + "'"+ " in parents and trashed=false and mimeType=application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
        FileList files = service.files().list().setQ(query).execute();

        List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
        Files.List request = service.files().list();

        do {
            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
        } while (request.getPageToken() != null && request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    }
```

I do **not** want to create additional requests **(new children request to each node)**  to see if it have children or not. something like that:

```
for (File file : result) {

             query = "'" + file.getId() + "'" + " in parents and trashed=false and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
             FileList fileChild = service.files().list().setQ(query).execute();
             List<File> res = new ArrayList<File>();
             Files.List req = service.files().list();

                do {
                    res.addAll(fileChild.getItems());
                    req.setPageToken(fileChild.getNextPageToken());
                } while (req.getPageToken() != null && req.getPageToken().length() > 0);


            RemoteFolder remFolder = new RemoteFolder();
            remFolder.setFile(file);
            if(res.size()>0){
                remFolder.setChildrenable(true);
                log.info("folder named "+file.getTitle() + " have children folders count: "+ res.size());
            }

            folderList.add(remFolder);

        }
```

I want to optimize my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make another request for each node. If you want to avoid too many calls use memcached.

Comment: what does the memcached mean? I dont know. Yes I do another request for each node. I have that code written in my question. Can I optimize it to be more faster? or how to create memcached here?